# Classification - modified huber loss: how is it more tolerant to outliers?

Tags: scikit-learn, classification, svm, outliers

According to the scikit-learn SGDClassifier [documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.SGDClassifier.html) , modified Huber loss function can be used to offer higher tolerance to outliers.

Having a look at the [plot](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/linear_model/plot_sgd_loss_functions.html) of the cost function though, doesn't it seem like Modified Huber is *less* tolerant? It appears to give higher cost to observations with f(x)<0, i.e. to observations that lie on the wrong side of the margin. Isn't this correct?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that the scikit-learn docs say nothing about *which* baseline loss function we should compare Modified Huber's tolerance to outliers to.

Modified Huber loss stems from Huber loss, which is used for regression problems. Looking at this [plot](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Huber_loss.svg#/media/File:Huber_loss.svg), we see that Huber loss has a higher tolerance to outliers than squared loss. As you've noted, other loss functions are much more tolerant to outliers, with the exception of squared hinge loss.